# filter objects by an array of objects rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `@selected_posts` - an array of `selected_post` objects.
Each `selected_post` has  name and info.

And I have another activerecord model

```
PublishedPost  < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And I need to select all published posts where

```
published_post.name == selected_post.name and published_post.info== selected_post.info
```

How do I do this?

I think of something like:

```
PublishedPost.where("name in ? AND info in ?", @selected_posts.map(&:name) @selected_posts.map(&:info))
```

Comment: Should you really have `PublishedPost` as a separate class in the first place? You can most likely do what you are doing by just using an [enum column](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) on the posts table. `enum status: [:draft, :published, :trashed]`

Comment: yes, I should have `PublishedPost` as separate table  because database structure is already defined and written not by me

Answer (score 0):

The trouble there is that if you have a one selected post with the same name as a published post and a different selected post with the same info as the same published post, the published post will be selected based on two different selected posts.  I'm not sure that's what you want.

Better would be to make a join wiithout using primary keys.

have a join defined in the PublishedPost class using name instead of primary key.

```
class PublishedPost

  belongs_to :selected_post, foreign_key: 'name', primary_key: 'name', optional: true

end
```

Now you can do...

```
@published_posts = PublishPost.join(:selected_post).where(selected_posts: @selected_posts).where("selected_posts.info = published_posts.info")
```

Answer (score 0):

First collect the `name` and `info` in single loop:

```
all_names, all_info = Array.new, Array.new
@selected_posts.each do |sp|
  all_names << sp.name
  all_info << sp.info
end
```

Then use it in query as you have already thought as below:

```
PublishedPost.where(name: all_names, info: all_info)
```